# How to align column header with data(checkbox header and checkbox data) in react table using semantic ui react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table, semantic-ui-react

How to align 1st column (checkbox header and checkbox data) in react table using semantic ui react

[image: Table consists of 3 columns for now]

<Table.Body> .map((el) => { return ( <Table.Row key={el.report_ref_no}> <Table.Cell> {" "} {" "} </Table.Cell>

Comment: Add some code snippets also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS
verticalAlign = 'middle'
textAlign = 'center'